# How to compile/build restlet 2.2 modules?

Tags: restlet, restlet-2.0

I have cloned the restlet codebase from github and I am working on 2.2 branch. However I am not able to build the modules as it doesn't have pom.xml in any of the module.

I have previously worked with restlet 2.1 branch wherein I was able to compile the modules without any problem.

How do I build modules ? Can I just copy the pom.xml from 2.1 branch or is there any specific process for 2.2

Comment: I see the pom.xml in here https://github.com/restlet/restlet-framework-java/tree/2.2/modules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually built with ant from the **build** sub-folder

https://github.com/restlet/restlet-framework-java/tree/2.2/build

Comment: Additional info here: https://github.com/restlet/restlet-framework-java/wiki/Building-the-source